# Is it possible to get a Schengen visa and travel one month later from the date of issue?

Tags: schengen, invitation-letters, schengen-visas

I'm in Indian National living in Ireland on a student visa which expires in October, 2016. I wanted to travel to Greece to meet my girlfriend who is Greek, so I booked tickets for August, 2016.

I didn't know back then that my Irish visa needs to be valid for at least 3  months on the date when I get the Schengen visa, so I can't get a visa starting from August since it's less than 3 months and now I stand to lose all my plane ticket money since the flight is non refundable.

If I book a refundable ticket to Greece for July, and use that for the visa application, then finally cancel it once I get the visa, and travel in August, will this be possible? Or will I be stopped at the immigration in Greece because I would be traveling a month later?

And if I do this, would I need two invitation letters from my girlfriend, inviting me to stay over, one for the visa application and one which I'll carry with me for August?

Comment: There's always a chance that your visa will be limited in duration so that it expires before your August trip.  But if it isn't, then your plan might work.

Comment: Are you sure the condition is that your current residence has to be valid for three months after _issuance_ of the visa? I can't find an explicit rule either way in the Visa Code, but the corresponding rule about _passport_ validity counts from the _expiry_ date of the visa.

Comment: That's what I thought when I bought the ticket, but when I called the embassy of Greece, they said a valid visa of the country where I'm currently resident for at least 3 months is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If your visa would still be valid by August, it's perfectly fine to go to Greece then.

However the Greek consulate will likely issue a limited-validity visa that would only be valid for July, unless it's not your first Schengen visa.